# unrecognized selector sent to instance in MapView iof OS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently using Xcode 6;

While generating map view in iOS 8.1 using Mapkit.h and coreLocation framework,on clicking the button instead of showing latitude and longitude values in labels it's showing crash error as:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x797a4e20

in GPSController.m

```
- (IBAction)tap:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"button clicked");
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

}
```

should fetch the value in this:

```
 (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations 
{
    NSLog(@"location info object=%@", [locations lastObject]);
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];

    NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
    self.lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+.6f", location.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longi.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+.6f", location.coordinate.longitude];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Map" sender:self];

}
```

Comment: Show the complete error message.  It should be telling you the exact class and selector that is unrecognized.  You should also identify exactly which line it crashes on.

Comment: Go to the breakpoints tab (Cmd+7), press `+` and add an `Exception Breakpoint`. Now it should crash on the line which calls the unrecognised selector.

Comment: Error Log:[GPSViewController locationError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a979070
(lldb)

Comment: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self.delegate locationError:error]; //error at this point
}

Comment: what is self.delegate ?? is it implementing the method() locationError:

Comment: [code](import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h"

- (void)update:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;

NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
)
//CoreLocationController.h

Comment: **Show the complete error message and exception stack trace!!!**  These should *always* be included when reporting an Objective-C runtime error (or one in any other language, for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform following reviews in your code.

1. Check if **‘tap’ IBAction is binded with some cocoa control element** (say UIbutton touchUpInside event)
2. Check if **‘tap’ IBAction has been declared in Class**
3. You may be using `action:@selector(tap:)` instead of `action:@selector(tap)`
4. Handle `didFailWithError` delegate of Location Manager to get more detail about error
   Syntax:

   (void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager       didFailWithError: (NSError *) error
5. Check of **Segue with ID ‘Map’ does exists**

Answer (score 0):

you should also give definition of

```
(void)locationError:(NSError *)error in{
```

//your logic
}